# How to get an adaptive frame which fits auto-wrapped text?

Tags: front-end

When using the built-in Debugger, the breakpoints and the current step will be framed looks like this:

[image]

My favorite part is, those frames are **adaptive** to the text when window width changing makes it auto-wrapped to a different shape:

[image]

So my question is:

How can I programmly get a frame with this kind of adaptive behavior, as good performance (executing fast) as possible?

Comment: Define "efficient." Do you mean shortest code, fastest code, or something else?

Comment: @rcollyer Sorry for the ambiguousness. I would like a code executing as fast as possible. I have edited my descriptions. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap#Minimum_raggedness

Comment: @ziyuang Thanks for your information. But what I concern is not how to wrap text but how to draw the irregular frame around given text.

Comment: @Silvia I think you can draw the frame after you wrap the text by surrounding your wrapped text, if I understand your question correctly. Or are you asking whether there is a built-in function for this purpose since this effect appears in Mathematica?

Comment: @ziyuang A built-in function is of course the best. But I doubt there is any. What I want to ask is exact how to "draw the frame after you wrap the text by surrounding your wrapped text".

Answer (score 6):

This is hacky, but it works:

```
front = Pane[
 Style["this is a test and I hope it works so I need a very long string",    
 Background -> Yellow], ImageSize -> 150]
```

[image]

```
back = Pane[
  Style["this is a test and I hope it works so I need a very long string",
  Background -> Red], ImageSize -> 150, ImageMargins -> 2]
```

[image]

```
Overlay[{MinFilter[Rasterize@back, 2], front}, Alignment -> Center, 
 ImageMargins -> 1]
```

[image]

There are a few artefacts where the text hits the edge of the background in the back copy, and therefore the black color is picked up in the `MinFilter`. As shown below you can fix this by setting the text color and the background color in the back copy the same.

You could build this up into a function like this:

```
borderedText[text_String, width_Integer?Positive, {color1_, color2_}] :=
 With[{f = Pane[Style[text, Background -> color1], ImageSize -> width], 
   b = Pane[Style[text, color2, Background -> color2], ImageSize -> width, ImageMargins -> 2]},
  Overlay[{MinFilter[Rasterize@b, 2], f}, Alignment -> Center, ImageMargins -> 1]]

borderedText["This is a test that might or might not work", 150, 
{Lighter@Yellow, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Verbeia. Thank you for your answer! It's really clever! Though I don't have access to a MMA, but it looks promising. Do you think it could be made to work in an `"Input"` style cell, so we can block-mark the code without affecting its executability?