# How does the built-in debugger decide what to highlight?

Tags: notebooks, debugging

How does the built-in debugger decide which definition to highlight in the notebook when Break on messages" is enabled?

Here's an example to illustrate what I mean.  First, enable the debugger (Evaluation -> Debugger), then define a function that issues a message:

```
f::boo:="Boo!!!";
f[]:=Module[{a,b,c,d},
  a=1;
  b=a;
  Message[f::boo];
  c=b;
  d=c;
  a+b+c+d
]
```

When running `f[]`, evaluation will pause on the message and the point where the break occurred will be highlighted:

[image]

Now let's re-assign its own DownValues to `f`, and re-run it.  Now this second definition will be highlighted, but not the original one.

[image]

**The question:** How does the debugger know what to highlight and can we influence this somehow?  I would like the definition printed by [this spelunking tool](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/12) to be highlighted, if possible.

Comment: How did you get the debugger to do something sensible at all?

Comment: @Yves I know that the common opinion is that the debugger is not very useful, but every time I look at the other proposed solutions I find that much of what I need is already implemented more conveniently in the debugger.  The unreliable part is only this highlighting that I'm asking about now, but the "break on messages" functionality, the stack window, and the ability to look at the values of local variables (e.g. Module) are immensely useful.  It also puts you in a `Dialog[]` on break, so you can evaluate anything and examine the kernel state in detail.

Comment: @Yves I think most of the frustration comes from people trying to set breakpoints, like in debuggers for other languages.  If you avoid this, and avoid relying on highlighting, it works pretty well.

Comment: I think that there is a bigger problem here. Imperative languages are statement-based, and tend to work by breaking things into small pieces (such as array elements) and working on them separately. This makes it easy and natural to inspect those, and monitor the execution step by step. Functional languages are doing something else typically: they are optimized to work on trees of various sorts. Inspecting the steps here would very often involve the inspection of rather large structures at every step, and it is this issue IMO which makes the conventional debugging harder here.

Comment: So, the "functional debugger" would rather be a device which would trim the larger structures we actually work on to some smaller sizes, appropriate for inspection. This is hard to automate. Therefore, debugging of well-written functional programs normally would consist of code dissection and inspection of the data transformation steps, which usually can be taken out of the context and tested by themselves (due to immutability). So, for functional code, a big part of debugging actually happens right when we write the code, since the better it is written, the easier it is to debug it.

Comment: @Leonid "So, for functional code, a big part of debugging actually happens right when we write the code, since the better it is written, the easier it is to debug it." <-- I agree with this very much.  This is why I haven't used the built-in debugger much.  But what if you need to look at and understand someone else's code?  Actually this question was motivated by [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20580/high-memory-use-while-exporting-a-bmp).  I noticed that when I changed the `DownValues`, the debugger suddenly start highlighting, and I wonder how I can make use of this

Comment: @Szabolcs I think that we have not yet explored all the possibilities that Mathematica meta-programming gives us in this respect. I would agree that some kind of debugger would be very useful, I am just not sure that the current built-in one is the one I would choose. I did not yet invest enough time into this (there is an alternative debugger by David Bailey, perhaps some other useful tools exist and /or can be created), but I also feel that there can be something very useful that we are missing here.

Comment: @szabolcs: Can debugger display local variables defined within Module? Could you show an example? Everytime I try entering the name of a local variable at a breakpoint within a module, it ended up showing only the global variable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*(It's interesting I asked [a similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15516/17) before. As your question is a superset of mine, I would like to post the answer here.)*

About the first question: *How does the debugger know what to highlight?* I don't really know the internal mechanism, but I hope this answer can provide some possible tiny clues.

About the second question: *Can we influence this somehow?* In the following text, I will try to simulate the highlighter of the built-in Debugger by somehow hacky way.

## Preparation

Some critical built-in functions we are going to use:

- **`` FrontEnd`NotebookInterfaceObject ``, `` FrontEnd`DebuggerSelect ``**

  Those functions can by found when checking the `Stack[_]` during Debugger breaks. The `` FrontEnd`NotebookInterfaceObject ``, I guess, is a kind of FrontEnd objects associated with (nearly) all expressions separately.

  > *e.g.* `(1 + 2)/3 + 1` :
  >
  > `1 + 2` <--> `NotebookInterfaceObject[1]`
  >
  > `(1 + 2)/3` <--> `NotebookInterfaceObject[2]`
  >
  > `(1 + 2)/3 + 1` <--> `NotebookInterfaceObject[3]`

  [image: gif animation: DebuggerSelect]

  - **Sidenote:** It seems `` FrontEnd`DebuggerSelect `` is available only when Debugger is enabled, but there is another function `` FrontEnd`SelectObject `` which seems always usable.
- **`DebugTag`**

  Although by using `NotebookInterfaceObject`, we can refer to any expression displayed in the FrontEnd, the problem is how we can FIND the corresponding object identity numbers.

  I only found a partial solution really by accident.

  With **Debugger enabled**, we set `$PreRead` as

  ```
  $PreRead = (Print[#]; #) &
  ```

  Then we evaluate the above example

  ```
  (1 + 2)/3 + 1
  ```

  > ```
  > RowBox[{
  >  TagBox[RowBox[{
  >     TagBox[RowBox[{"(",
  >        TagBox[
  >         RowBox[{"1", "+", "2"}],
  >         DebugTag[22769]],
  >        ")"}],
  >      DebugTag[22753]],
  >     "/", "3"}],
  >   DebugTag[22737]],
  >  "+", "1"}]
  > ```

  Note the numbers in `DebugTag`s. Using the `` FrontEnd`DebuggerSelect `` function, it's not hard to verify that those numbers are exactly the object identity numbers of the box expressions in the corresponding `TagBox`.

  - **Sidenote:** The following experiment might reveal more details about `DebugTag` and `NotebookInterfaceObject`.

    With Debugger enabled and `$PreRead` set as above, type `1 + 1/2` somewhere in an Input cell, select the cell and trigger **Convert To InputForm** (or any other *Form*. For *InputForm* it's <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Windows). It can be seen that every time we trigger the convert, a different set of identify numbers are sent to `DebugTag` then `$PreRead`.

    [image: gif animation: DebugTag]

    So I guess, the `NotebookInterfaceObject`s are allocated when an expression is **rendered** in FrontEnd, and Debugger somehow interrupts this process and adds the `DebugTag`s. All of this happen in FrontEnd, before anything is passed to `$PreRead`.

## Defination Highlighter

This section we use the functions described in **Preparation** to simulate the highlighter of the built-in Debugger, with full control about how and what to highlight.

The basic idea is to use Debugger to parse the input, then to intercept the `DebugTag`ed expression at `$PreRead` and modify it so highlight actions are injected at every level whenever a `DebugTag` present, then to pass it to `$SyntaxHandler`, `$Pre`, etc. for standard evaluation.

- **boxHighlighter**

  `boxHighlighter` is used to perform the highlight action.

  ```
  Clear[boxHighlighter]
  boxHighlighter[num_, time_: 1] :=
   Block[{},
    MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
     FrontEnd`DebuggerSelect[FrontEnd`NotebookInterfaceObject[num]]];
    Pause[time]]
  ```
- **highlightScanWrapper**

  `highlightScanWrapper` is used to inject `boxHighlighter` into every expression level with the help of `TraceScan`.

  ```
  Clear[highlightScanWrapper]
  highlightScanWrapper[def_, time_] :=
   RowBox[{"TraceScan", "[",
     RowBox[{
       RowBox[{RowBox[{"(",
           RowBox[{
             RowBox[{
               RowBox[{RowBox[{"boxHighlighter", "[", 
                   RowBox[{"#", ",", ToString[time]}], "]"}], "&"}],
               "@@",
               RowBox[{"ReleaseHold", "[", "#", "]"}]
               }], ";",
             "#"}],
           ")"}], "&"}], ",",
       def, ",",
       RowBox[{"dtnum", "[", "_", "]"}]
       }],
     "]"}]
  ```
- **dtTagTransformation**

  `dtTagTransformation` is used to perform transformation from `TagBox[expr_,DebugTag[num_]]` to `CompoundExpression` like `(dtnum[num]; expr)`.

  ```
  Clear[dtTagTransformation]
  dtTagTransformation[def_] := def //.
   (* Strip out TagBox around Sequences and Lists
      to prevent syntax error like If[a, b] -> If[(dtnum[];a, b)]: *)
      TagBox[RowBox[{a : (PatternSequence[_, ","] ..), b_}], DebugTag[_]] :>
             RowBox[{a, b}] //.
      TagBox[RowBox[{"{", contents___, "}"}], DebugTag[_]] :>
             RowBox[{"{", contents, "}"}] //.
   (* Transformation rule for others: *)
      TagBox[expr_, DebugTag[dtnum_]] :>
             RowBox[{"(",
               RowBox[{
                 RowBox[{"dtnum", "[", ToString[dtnum], "]"}], ";",
                 expr
                 }], ")"}]
  ```
- **parse enviroment**

  We use `parseBegin[time]` to establish the defination tracing and highlighting environment, where the `time` argument is used to specify how long should the highlighter pause at any highlighting. The default value is 1 second.

  When entering the parse enviroment, defination performed by any member of `defSymbolSet` will be parsed.

  ```
  defSymbolSet = {":=", "=", "^:=", "^=", ":>", "\[RuleDelayed]", "->", "\[Rule]"};

  Clear[parseBegin, parseEnd, parseExit]
  parseBegin[time_: 1] :=
   Block[{$highlightFunc},
    CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"DebuggerSettings", "ShowTools"}] = False;
    CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"DebuggerSettings", "ShowBreakpoints"}] = False;
    CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"DebuggerSettings", "ShowStack"}] = False;
    CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"DebuggerSettings", "BreakOnAllMessages"}] = False;
    CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"DebuggerSettings", "BreakOnAsserts"}] = False;
    CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"DebuggerSettings", "DebuggerEnabled"}] = True;
    $PreRead = (
      If[MatchQ[#, RowBox[{"parseEnd" | "parseExit", "[", "]"}]],
               $PreRead =.; #,
           # //. RowBox[{
                TagBox[funcPtn_, DebugTag[fdtnum_]],
                defSymbol_ /; MemberQ[defSymbolSet, defSymbol],
                def_}] :>
              RowBox[{
                funcPtn //. TagBox[expr_, DebugTag[_]] :> expr,
                defSymbol,
                $highlightFunc@TagBox[def, DebugTag[fdtnum]]
                }] /.
            $highlightFunc ->
                 (highlightScanWrapper[dtTagTransformation[#], time] &)
                ] &);
    Null]

  parseEnd[] := Null

  parseExit[] :=
   Block[{},
    CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"DebuggerSettings", "DebuggerEnabled"}] = False;
    CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"DebuggerSettings", "ShowTools"}] = True;
    Null]
  ```

## Usage Example

```
Clear[testFunc]
parseBegin[.2]
```

The actual defination code need to be input in a new cell (I believe this inconvenience can be fixed):

```
testFunc[x_ /; x < 1] := Module[{a, b, c},
  b := a + Cos[x];
  a := Sin[x];
  c = a + b;
  c + x
  ]

testFunc[x_ /; x > 1] := If[x < 1, testFunc[x], testFunc[x/2]]

DownValues[testFunc] = Join[DownValues[testFunc],
   {
    HoldPattern[testFunc[1]] :> testFunc[RandomReal[{0, 2}]]
    }];
```

(cell break)

```
parseEnd[]
```

Now we test this `testFunc` function:

```
testFunc[2]
```

[image: gif animation: parseTest]

```
parseExit[]
```