# See Local Variable at breakpoint within MODULE?

Tags: debugging

Within the debugger, can we watch local variables within a Module?

As the screenshot shows, the “i” only display its global value (12) upon a message breakpoint. Is there a way to show its local value?
[image]

```
Clear[i];
```

i = 12;
f[] := Module[{i},
   For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, Print[i]; Print[":\t"]; Print[i/0]];
   ];

f[]

Jimmy

Comment: Hummm... I would say that Mathematica debugger is not a good option for debug. I hope that the new Wolfram Language could came with a new Wolfram Debugger. :p

Comment: It is not showing the local value because it is not really `i` within the module - it's some temporary variable.

Comment: @vf1: Do you know how to get the actual name of the temporary variable so we can watch them, like in Visual studio?

Comment: @Murta: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20690/how-does-the-built-in-debugger-decide-what-to-highlight), user Szabolcs metioned that the debugger is "immensely helpful" because it can watch local variable. Any idea on how he achieved that?

Comment: @Murta: the previous link was wrong, please see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20690/how-does-the-built-in-debugger-decide-what-to-highlight)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

I figured it out - never used the debugger in MMA before so that's why I improvised. The `Stack` window has a "Local variables" tab - just open that:
[image]

**Old answer**

You can get the actual temporary name of the variable by printing it before it has a value. I'll see if there's a nicer solution.

[image]

Comment: This is however not sufficient. For example, what if "i" is the index of an array and we want to display value of myArray[i]? The small expandable "Local variable" icon shows only the value, but that value cannot be used.

Comment: @JimmyLin your question states "Is there a way to show its local value?" - for the time being, you can copy and paste. If you're looking for a Visual Studio level of debugging, I recommend Wolfram Workbench.

Comment: @JimmyLin even copy/paste is unnecessary - you can directly edit the local variables cell.

Comment: If you change "Module" to "Block", could you notice any difference? On my machine now I can access (both view and edit) the local variable.

Comment: Could you show the command to print local variable "i"'s name "i$xxx"? I find it useful, but seems you have replaced the old answer with the newer one.

Comment: My old answer is below my new one - it has always been there. Within the `Manipulate`, I have `Print[i];` before the `For`-loop to print the variable name.

Comment: @JimmyLin if you can see the value, why can't you evaluate your `array[[value]]` to see it?

Comment: @VF1:I see that! Seems Print[] shows actual variable name only when it is not yet assigned a value.