# Ways to obtain a BoxObject

Tags: front-end, notebooks, undocumented, boxes

Is there any way to get a [`BoxObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxObject.html), except with [`EvaluationBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationBox.html) or [`ParentBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParentBox.html)?

So usually one needs to create objects with `Initialization` or `Button` and use `EvaluationBox`.

I would love to see more flexible approach, e.g., how to get a `Box` object from the current selection.

I was only able to find:

> `BoxObject` expressions are typically generated using `EvaluationBox`.

which isn't much help.

The reason behind this question is that one can do interesting things with `Cell` or `Box` objects, the only problem is to get the required references.

Comment: Could it be related to the `` FrontEnd`NotebookInterfaceObject`` I mentioned in [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27120/17)?

Comment: Hmm... Anyway very interesting question! I wanted a generic box-object extractor for a long time...

Comment: It looks like what the `DebugTag` returned is the IDs of the Boxes in the Input line, while the `Dynamic[EvaluationBox]` gives the Box inside the `DynamicBox` in the Output Cell. The IDs I think are in the some index sequence.

Comment: ref/BoxObject is not one of the better efforts of WRI documentation staff, is it?

Answer (score 3):

This is by no means a complete answer, or maybe no answer at all. I will show how to detect at least some BoxObjects in a displayed notebook, not how to construct them. Partly this was done already by @Silvia in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27120/20253). She constructed some `FrontEnd'NotebookInterfaceObject`s and I will show that they indeed agree with `BoxObject`s. Then I will find some more `BoxObject`s in a given notebook, with an embarassing result.

First a slight modification of the ingenious technique used by Silvia.

Start a fresh Mathematica session and evaluate the next command.

```
$PreRead=(Print[#];#)&;
```

Activate the debugger and evaluate

```
(1+2)/3+1
```

Deactivate the debugger and evaluate

```
Clear[$PreRead]
```

The printed box structure shows some `DebugTag`s, of which the numbers correspond to  `FrontEnd'NotebookInterfaceObject`s, as shown by Silvia. Here I construct `BoxObject`s with the same numbers:

```
Cases[ NotebookGet[SelectedNotebook[]] , {___,PatternSequence["DebugTag","[",n_,"]"],___}:>BoxObject[ToExpression[n]], Infinity]
```

A nice property of `BoxObject`s is that when we click on the displayed number, the selection moves to the corresponding box structure. In this way we simply verify that these `BoxObject`s coincide with the `FrontEnd'NotebookInterfaceObject`s.

On my system, this way of finding `BoxObject`s was not quite stable. Sometimes I found 4 boxes, sometimes 6.

Now I try to find more `BoxObject`s in the notebook. For an existing `BoxObject`, we can inspect the contents with `NotebookRead`. If the box does not exist, the result will be `$Failed`. In the following command, we look for all `BoxObject`s in a certain range having non-empty contents. If we leave out the second condition in the `If` statement, we find some empty `BoxObject`s as well, whatever that may mean.

```
Table[With[{z=NotebookRead[BoxObject[n]]},
   If[z=!=$Failed && z=!={}, BoxObject[n], Nothing]], {n, 1, 6000}]
 Length[%]

(* list of displayed BoxObjects *)
(* 106 *)
```

The numbers of the found boxes all are 1 plus a multiple of 16:

```
Mod[%%[[All, 1]], 16] // Union
(* {1} *)
```

As already stated, clicking on a box number of a displayed `BoxObject` moves the selection to the corresponding box. By doing so, we see that sometimes a complete cell is a `BoxObject`, sometimes a single name or number is a `BoxObject`. It also happens that when we click on a box number, Mathematica crashes.

My final remark is a little bit outside the question. A `NotebookObject` or a `CellObject` can be used to change the displayed properties by using kernel commands on these objects. So I tried to do the same with a `BoxObject`:

```
SetOptions[BoxObject[2817], Background->Yellow]
```

Of course, the `BoxObject` was choosen such that the box indeed had the option `Background`. The effect of this command was that the background of the complete notebook became yellow. So I had to execute the above command once again, with `Yellow` replaced with `None`.

Comment: Interesting finding about the `Mod[..., 16]` one! +1

Comment: Don't write any production code based upon any of this.  If you use anything other than `ParentBox` or `EvaluationBox`, expect that, in some future version, your code will break.