# How to get frame around every function without any evaluation?

Tags: debugging, frame

Is there a good universal method that allows the making of a frame around every function. In the output, functions should remain unchanged (no evaluation, or any other changes) and each function should have frame.

For example, to make the frame around `Plus[1, Plus[Plus[1, 1], Plus[Plus[1, 1], 1]]]` something like `MakeNiceFrames[Plus[1, Plus[Plus[1, 1], Plus[Plus[1, 1], 1]]]]`. An output should look exactly same as in input `Plus[1, Plus[Plus[1, 1], Plus[Plus[1, 1], 1]]]` with every function (including head and closing bracket) separately framed.

*It will be nice to have that kind of framing for visual separations of functions while debugging. I have experimented with `Framed[]`. But each function needs the use of separate `Framed[]` function and functions are actually evaluated, what makes it makes inconvenient to use.*

Comment: Related: [15516](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15516/5478).

Comment: For formal clarity you should specify if you need framed function together with all its arguments or just the function's name framed (i suspect the former). A side note: triple-click any function name (Head) and it will be selected from Head start to the closing bracket. Perhaps somehow useful for this problem if you don't want to have too many frames, which could be confusing.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov First assumption is right. I edited question and part of it looks as "An output should look exactly same as in input `Plus[1, Plus[Plus[1, 1], Plus[Plus[1, 1], 1]]]` with every function (including head and closing bracket) separately framed." Do you think anything other should be added?

Comment: `TreeForm[Hold[
  Plus[1, Plus[Plus[1, 1], Plus[Plus[1, 1], 1]]]
  ]]` meets the use case in a different (and possibly more useful) way.

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

A slightly cleaner version of my first answer:

```
ReplaceAll[
    Inactivate[Plus[1,Plus[Plus[1,1],Plus[Plus[1,1],1]]]],
    Inactive[h_] :> Framed @* HoldForm[h]
]
```

**Original answer**

I don't know how useful this construct would be, but one idea is to use [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate):

```
ReplaceRepeated[
    Inactivate[Plus[1,Plus[Plus[1,1],Plus[Plus[1,1],1]]]],
    Inactive[h_][a___] :> Framed[HoldForm[h][a]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add how `Inactivate`, `HoldForm` and `Hold` differ. This seems to enable much shorter code than mine.

Answer (score 7):

> But each function needs the use of separate Framed[] function

Will solve it by using `RuleDelayed` and `Replace` with *levelspec*.

> and functions are actually evaluated, what makes it makes inconvenient to use.

Will keep it from evaluating using `Hold`.

```
f = Hold[Plus[1, Plus[Plus[1, 1], Plus[Plus[1, 1], 1]]]];
Replace[f, z_ :> Framed[z], {2, -1}]
```

[image]

And my attempt to keep the head from evaluating

```
f = Hold[Plus[1, Plus[Plus[1, 1], Plus[Plus[1, 1], 1]]]];
Replace[f, 
  z : h_[args___] :> Row[{h, Framed[Row[{args}, ","]]}], {1, -1}][[1]]

Replace[f, 
  h_[args___] :> 
   Row[{h, "[", Row[{args}, ","], "]"}, Frame -> True], {1, -1}][[1]]
```

[image]
[image]

To be honest, I was amazed when I learned `z:h_` kind of syntax. You can understand how it works, if you read carefully the description part of [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html).

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[frameAll]
frameAll = Map[Framed, # /. Inactive -> HoldForm, {0, -2}] &;

frameAll @ Inactivate[Plus[1,foo[1,1], Plus[Plus[1, 1], Plus[Times[1, 1,1], 1]]] ]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[frameAll2]
frameAll2 =  MapAll[#  /. h : _[__] :> Framed[h] &, # /. Inactive -> HoldForm] &;

frameAll2 @ Inactivate[Plus[1,foo[1,1], Plus[Plus[1, 1], Plus[Times[1, 1,1], 1]]] ]
```

> same result

```
ClearAll[frameAll3]
frameAll3 = Block[{Inactive = Framed @* HoldForm[##]&}, #]&

frameAll3 @ Inactivate[Plus[1,foo[1,1], Plus[Plus[1, 1], Plus[Times[1, 1,1], 1]]] ]
```

> same result